# Help with BJT Transistor analysis. The amplified waveform is more like a square wave any needs to be more sinusoidal

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt

I have been exploring BJT transistors and implemented a common base amplifier.  I connected a signal generator to the voltage source labelled V2 in the below schematic.  The oscilloscope image shows the input above the amplified waveform.  It appears that it is in fact working, 10.8/.288 amplification.  I wish to  possibly use it to amplify a dynamic mic.  I plan to reduce the amplification and/or control it by a potentiometer.  Anyways..... my question is this

Why is the amplified signal "squareish" and not a decent replication of the input signal.  It looks more like an amplified square wave.  I created the circuit in LTSpice and simulated it.  The simulation is shown below.  I am reading materian on bjt transisters and especially common base amps,how is this fixable?  Which resistor values should i look to change Rc, Re, or Both.  Should the current level be changed through the emitter.  With no signal generator, it is 205 micro amps on the real circuit.  Do I need to adjust the voltage biase on the base.  Thanks for nay advice.

[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvkuJ.jpg)
[image]

Comment: You are seriously overdriving the amplifier.  Reduce the input signal level and/or reduce the gain of the amplifier.

Comment: Jeffrey, what are you trying to achieve? How did you design this? What were the goals? We can't just go fix something, or suggest changes, without a clue about what qualifies as "success" to you.

Comment: @jonk I am trying to make an amplifier to take the small signal from a dynamic mic, which should be in the range of a few millivolts, and feed it to a ham radio transmitter.  Once fed, I wish to experiment with the level of amplification to see what "sounds best" on another radio.  The other radio will of course receive the transmitted signal with its volumn appropriately set.

Comment: @jonkI would like to use a potentiometer and "adjust the volumn" on the tx side until I find the optimal circuit.  I copied this circuit from the internet and understood how the gain and especially how the emitter resistance (.025 mv) works.  I took this circuit with these parameters from an internet circuit.  Success is when the amplified waveform does not look like a square wave.  I will try and adjust the amplification.

Comment: @Peter Bennett Thank you, I will try that.  I copied this from the internet.  It was meant to take a dynamic mic as input.  I fed it  point 4 volts peak to peak from my signal generator.  I will reduce the gain/modify it or try and lower my signal generator (unlikely).  My main issue is the replicated wave the fact that the top and bottom are not shaped the same.  I do not know how to adjust it so that the top and bottom look like they were mirrored, but I will try and lower the gain.

Comment: @Peter Bennett  Actually, when I made changes in LTSpice, with the gain, the wave form still did not resemble the sine wave that was fed in it.l

Comment: Insert a resistor inbetween the emitter and C2 (say 820R) to reduce the gain and replace  R1 with say 26k to adjust symmetry.

Comment: @JeffreyEdwardMessikian I remember, now. You had posted a schematic with three transistors and a 47k potentiometer on it. Coming back, now. Dynamic microphones will usually have a low output impedance, but very often include a transformer so that the output impedance is higher: perhaps \$600\:\Omega\$ but they can be as much as \$50\:\text{k}\Omega\$. And so that the output voltage is in a better range.

Comment: @JeffreyEdwardMessikian There's a reason I don't want to get into this design for you. "It's complicated." You should have a look at [Douglas Self's article in Wireless World, December 1987](https://www.americanradiohistory.com/UK/Wireless-World/80s/Wireless-World-1987-12.pdf) starting on page 1207 (page 26 of the PDF.) Read through that. The problem is the variations in dynamic microphones (at least, those many years ago) and the desire for low noise pre-amplifier designs. The focus is on the dynamic microphone model, which drives the design.

Comment: @JeffreyEdwardMessikian By the way, what makes you think that a \$200\:\text{mV}\$ peak input models a dynamic microphone input source? For all I know, this may be more like \$10\:\text{mV}\$ RMS for a typical microphone of that type. Have you made any measurements of your microphone outputs? And what will you be driving with the pre-amplifier output?

Comment: @jonk Thanks, I will review the linked article.  The circuit I used was likely made years ago.  The dynamic mic I am trying to fit is also an old design.  I just looked on the scope for the new mic and its variation is about 20mV peak to peak.  When I speak into it, that variation can jump considerably.  I used 200mV amplitude only because that was the minimum variation my signal generator could create without what appeared to be problems.  I had not considered excess gain and distortion in this project,  I figured what I would see at 400mV pk2pk variation would be what shows at 20mV p2p.

Comment: @jonk I will be driving the chip I linked in the earlier post, a DRA818V transmitter.  I think it has very high input impedance.  It just might be that I do not need this kind of an amplifier as input to the chip and I can just feed it the microphone.  In any case, I wanted to use the opportunity to deepen my understanding of this kind of an amplifier using a BJT.  So, the 200mV sig input and especially the gain is not realistic.  Maybe the gain only needs to be 5 or 10, I just wanted to see this and understand it completely.

Comment: @JeffreyEdwardMessikian Okay. So perhaps you just want to know how to design a CB amplifier that will work according to some specifications and will, if you build it and feed it a generated signal, also work as you expect when you scope it. If so, perhaps one of your questions (or a new one) could focus on that aspect. It's not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The current through the base-emitter junction of a transistor is governed by the diode equation: \$i_e = I_S \left(e^\frac{v_{be}}{n\ V_T} - 1\right)\$.  At room temperature, \$V_T \simeq 26\mathrm{mV}\$.  So unless your peak-peak input voltage is significantly smaller than \$26\mathrm{mV}\$, you'll get distortion.

On the bright side, you have lots of excess gain in that circuit.  The quickest way to get more linearity is to put a resistor in series with the emitter, between the emitter and the intersection of R4 and C2.  I think I'd start with a value somewhere between \$200\Omega\$ and \$1000\Omega\$ and see how things look.

And -- don't think for a second that your resistor values are realistic.  1% resistors are standard these days, yet still a bit absurd for a transistor stage like that because any real transistor that you plug in there will add far more variation than a 5% resistor will.

Comment: Well, the 1% resistors just mean that the design doesn't have to be compromised still further to handle large unknown resistor variations as well as everything else the design otherwise has to compromise in order to manage (such as part parameter variations, temperature...) One less thing to deal with is a nice-to-have, I think.

Comment: I implemented this circuit from a schematic.  The resistor values were described in standard sizes such as 10k, 47k.  I saw what I attached on the oscilloscope pic and decided to implement it in LTSpice.  I used a 20000 count LCR meter to obtain the actual resistor values in my circuit.  I used those values in LTSpice.    I skipped the caps.  Sadly, the LTSpice sim did not exactly match the oscilloscope, though I would say it is close.  I still need to look more at LTSpice and its sim.  I never saw the diode equation (current) related to BJT's so I will investigate that and its application hre

Comment: What I read/know about BJT's was mostly from the web site allaboutcircuits.com   I will dig more to understand the excess gain problem you say I have.  I will especially try and understand how the diode equation relates at low input values

Comment: If you have more than enough gain and lots of distortion, the gain isn't a problem -- it's a life saver.

Comment: The second-biggest reason your LTSpice simulation wouldn't match your circuit exactly is because transistors vary **a lot** from unit to unit.  The biggest is that it's a simulator, not the real thing -- you're supposed to understand that, and understand transistor theory, and understand what you can and cannot learn from simulation.  At your level, just remember that it's kinda approximate.

Comment: @TimWescott Thanks Tim, I do know transistors vary considerably.  As a simulator, I thought LTSpice had more muscle.  If you can list an equation above, it should be in the simulator/code.  Ltspice can allow me to vary Beta and likely other parameters of the sim. It seems to be pretty good.  I am new.  My level is that of a computer programmer turned into a finance professional.  All this is a hobby that I have learned on my own with posts to this web site and articles being read.  I have looked at other sites for input.My focus now is on how your equations fits into the other artices/sites

Comment: The Schokley diode equation *is* built into Spice's transistor model; that's why you're seeing the match between reality and simulation.  I should note that while you see the match as *bad*, I see the match as *very good*, and while most of my income has derived from lines of code, by training and off-and-on experience, I'm an analog circuit designer.